# How to boot Chromebook from SD card without entering developer mode?

Tags: sd-card, chromebook

I have a question. Is it at all possible to install Ubuntu or Chrubuntu onto a SD Card and then boot a chromebook from said SD card? I know this is easily possible, but the chromebook in question belongs to my school, so I cannot enter developer mode, because that would void the license agreement. I don't really care how technical or how many steps this will take, as long as it can be possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm John Smith and last year I wondered much of the same. In truth the answer is no. You'd have to go into developer mode because unlike most Windows & Mac pc's Chromebooks has an entirely different boot loader. If you start up the pc you can see that instead of your regular company logo(whoever made the pc) it just goes directly to Chrome Os. So instead of giving you boot up options at start up you have to go to developer mode if you want to change anything to do with the boot up. Sorry. But the good news is that if yo memory is backed up and your facts and method is straight, depending on your steps in developer mode Chrome Os will always be hiding on your pc and if something goes wrong it's easy to get back into Chrome Os.

Answer (score 1):

> ChrUbuntu: ChrUbuntu is a Ubuntu system built for Chromebooks. It works like a
>   traditional dual-boot system. You can restart your Chromebook and choose between
>   Chrome OS and Ubuntu at boot time. ChrUbuntu can be installed on your Chromebook’s
>   internal storage or on a USB device or SD card.
>
> Crouton: Crouton actually uses a “chroot” environment to run both Chrome OS and Ubuntu
>   at the same time. Ubuntu runs alongside Chrome OS, so you can switch between Chrome
>   OS and your standard Linux desktop environment with a keyboard shortcut. This gives you
>   the ability to take advantage of both environments without any rebooting needed. Crouton
>   allows you to use Chrome OS while having a standard Linux environment with all its
>   command-line tools and desktop applications a few keystrokes away.

the article is on [how-to-geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/) and walks you through the steps. there are also plenty of youtube videos that walk you through the process.

note: you should always do a backup on files that are important to you!

enable dev mode

download and install [type]

where [type] is either crouton or chrubuntu. the guide installs crouton.

alt keys to move between environs

what you can do with linux on chromebook

turn dev mod off when you want to restore

this process is dependent upon the type of chromebook

site:

Comment: Chromebooks use their own boot system, different than the system on any normal PC.

Comment: i know that now. lol i totally forgot about this post. sorry about that.